# How to dissect a field in an already dissected package in Wireshark using Lua?

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I have a protocol that is built on UDP and that is partly dissected by a third party dll in Wireshark. I now want to create a custom dissector to apply to the remaining field "data".

Is it possible to do so and should I use a dissector, post-dissector or a listener or a combination of them to accomplish this? Or do I have to re-write the third party dissector to one that calls my dissector on the remaining data?

Comment: You might want to see the Wireshark Q&A site http://ask.wireshark.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As John Zwinck mentioned, you probably do want something like a chained dissector, which you can manage fairly straightforwardly in either Lua or C. To that end, you certainly do want to implement your logic as a dissector. In Lua, something like this:

```
do
    --TODO set up your extra "data" field
    local tcp_table = DissectorTable.get("tcp.port")
    local third_party_dissector tcp_table:get_dissector(PROTO_PORT)

    function your_protocol.dissector(tvb, pinfo, tree)
         --call the third party dissector
         third_party_dissector:call(tvb, pinfo, tree)
         --TODO do what you need with the data
    end

    --take over the port your protocol runs over
    tcp_table_add(PROTO_PORT, your_protocol)
end
```

Keep the [API](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/wsluarm.html) on hand, but keep in mind also that Lua dissectors in Wireshark are really just for prototyping; they are less efficient than equivalent C-based dissectors, and the API tends to lag several versions behind the C dissection API.

Answer (score 2):

When I wanted to do something like this I found it surprisingly complex and unpleasant (relative to Lua dissector development in general).  There is some mention of "chained dissectors" here: http://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua/Dissectors .  From what I read (I never did get mine working, but I didn't try too hard), it seems easier to make chained dissectors in C than in Lua.  Still, try following the example on that page, which thankfully has enough comments to make it pretty clear.

Comment: Yeah, I feel the same way. Makes me want to write a packet analyzer in Haskell... :) Thanks, missed that one. Unfortunately I could not get it to work. Might be that I'm forced to use a really old version of Wireshark (0.99.7).